# How to get my image gallery into my product.html in Django with Class based view DetailView

Tags: django, detailview

I am using model Product and Images. my goal is to display in my singe item page a gallery of item related pictures coming from model "Images"

How can i change the following code to filter by item slug and only show gallery specific to the slug.

> Item class

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(, upload_to='catalog/images/', blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
```

> Images class

```
class Images(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='catalog/images/', blank=True)
```

> Product detail view

```
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'product.html'
    context_object_name = 'item'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['image_gallery'] = Images.objects.all()
        return context
```

> product.html page

```
<div class="row wow fadeIn">
        
        {% for img in image_gallery %}
          
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4">
          
          <img src="{{img.image.url}}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          
        </div>
```

Comment: `context['image_gallery'] = Images.objects.all().filter(pk=self.object.pk)`

Comment: @Crosby this solution only shows 1 picture in the gallery. in the database the product has 3 images. and I am using the slug. how can I make sure all 3 pictures show in the gallery?

Comment: ```context['image_gallery'] = Images.objects.filter(item=self.object)``` should work i think ?

Comment: @Brioproject I wrote it as an answer. Can you validate it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the instance of image with `self.object`, then you just need to filter the images you want to pass to the view with the foreign key relationship.

```py
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'product.html'
    context_object_name = 'item'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['image_gallery'] = Images.objects.filter(item=self.object)
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .filter() not .get()

```
image = Images.objects.all()
image.image will give you the image
```

This is Django 3 you need to convert it to whatever version you are using